# How to auto generate a text field based on a drop down box selection

Tags: mysql, forms

I have a small form field that has as `dropdown <name="product">` this list is generated by pulling data from a mysql table.

The mysql DB is setup as following:

Table Product:

```
  Column: Product
  Column: Product ID
```

Table Contact:

```
  Column: Product ID
  Column: Contact Name
  Column: Contact name #2
  Column: Contact Name #3
  Column: Contact name #4
```

Based on what a user selects in the pulldown list, I want to query the database again to datafill 4 new text boxes:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

The intent of the form will also capture some other data and submit it to a separate database, which leads me into how to tie in two DB's.

Thanks.

Comment: I Should note that the product selected in the pull down list will take the Prodcut ID to obtain the contacts in the second database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one:

1. When preparing the page, query all the `Contact` row columns and put them into a JavaScript array on the page. There output could look something like this (there are plenty of correct ways to implement this):

   ```
   <script language=JavaScript>
   var contactInfo = new Array(
     {prodID: 1, name1: 'aaaa', name2: 'bbbb', name3: 'cccc', name4: 'dddd'},
     {prodID: 4, name1: 'eeee', name2: 'ffff', name3: 'gggg', name4: 'hhhh'},
     ...
     {prodID: 90, name1: 'wwww', name2: 'xxxx', name3: 'yyyy', name4: 'zzzz'}
   );
   ```
2. In the dropdown list's `onchange`, call a function to handle the `productID` selection:

   ```
   <select name="ddlProductID" onchange="processProductChange(this);">
   ```
3. Make sure you have the textboxes defined. For this example I'll call them `txtName1` through `txtName4`:

   ```
   <input type=text name="txtName1">
   ...
   <input type=text name="txtName1">
   ```
4. In the called function, get the dropdown list's value and locate it in the `contactInfo` array. That will lead you to the names, and you can pop them into the textboxes:

   ```
   function processProductChange(prodDropdown) {
     for (indx = 0; indx < contactInfo.length; ++indx) {
       if (contactInfo[indx].prodID == prodDropdown.value {
          // The product ID has been located in the array. Put its names
          // in the txtName1 through txtName4 textboxes.
          document.forms[0].txtName1.value = contactInfo[indx].name1;
          document.forms[0].txtName2.value = contactInfo[indx].name2;
          document.forms[0].txtName3.value = contactInfo[indx].name3;
          document.forms[0].txtName4.value = contactInfo[indx].name4;
          // all done, can get out
          break;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

---

**Addendum**: OP asked for more detail on this approach. This requires some PHP code, which I'm not that good at, but I know enough that I'll first give the obligatory warning about using the `mysql` PHP functions. Here goes...

**The PHP `mysql` functions are deprecated. Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.**

Now back to the answer. As mentioned, my PHP isn't that good, but basically you want to format the `{prodID: ... }` lines of the script from step 1 while populating the dropdown list; that way you only need to scan the results once. It would go something like this (interspersed in the code the OP provided in the comment):

```
<?php
$jsArray = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($productlist)) {
   $rowmod = strtr($row['ProductID']," ","_"); // change the spaces to underscore to work in URL line
   if (jsArray) {
     // comma between elements
     jsArray .= ",";
   }
   jsArray .= "\n{prodID: {$row['ProductID']}, ";
   jsArray .= "name1: \"{$row['Name1']}\", ";
   jsArray .= "name2: \"{$row['Name2']}\", ";
   jsArray .= "name3: \"{$row['Name3']}\", ";
   jsArray .= "name4: \"{$row['Name4']}\"}";
   echo "<option value='$rowmod'>$row[ProductElement]</option>";
}
?>
```

Then when you can safely place the JavaScript (say after the closing `<form>` tag, do this:

```
<? php
echo <<< endJS
 <script language="JavaScript">
  var contactInfo = new Array($jsArray);

  NOTE: PASTE THE FUNCTION FROM STEP 4 HERE

 </script>
endJS;
?>
```

Chances are there's an error or two in the code here, so some debugging will likely be needed.

Comment: Thanks Ed, as I am a little new to all this it would be great if you can provide a little more detail. Here is the code that I use to create my dropdown: <?php
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($productlist))
  {
  $rowmod = strtr($row['ProductID']," ","_"); // change the spaces to underscore to work in URL line
  echo "<option value='$rowmod'>$row[ProductElement]</option>"; 
  }
  ?>

Comment: I've added an example to the answer. My PHP is pretty weak (I use .NET about 95% of the time) so errors are likely, but it should show the general approach. Good luck!